# postgis convert Points to polygon

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgis

what is the easy way to convert points to polygon?

i've tried this query

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((157 -536.0,157 -537.0,157 -538.0,157 -539.0,157 -540.0,157 -541.0,157 -542.0,157 -543.0,157 -544.0,157 -545.0,158 -545.0,159 -545.0,160 -545.0,161 -545.0,162 -545.0,163 -545.0,164 -545.0,165 -545.0,165 -544.0,165 -543.0,165 -542.0,165 -541.0,165 -540.0,165 -539.0,165 -538.0,165 -537.0,165 -536.0,164 -536.0,163 -536.0,162 -536.0,161 -536.0,160 -536.0,159 -536.0,158 -536.0,157.0 -536.0))');
```

but its results are not as expected as shown below

[image]

which is supposed to be like this

[image]

Comment: For one thing, you have two main discrete polygons there, plus a couple of small ones. PostGIS appears to support this with the MultiPolygon type. So I suggest isolating your points into closed sets (in the correct order), creating polygons from each, and making a multipolygon from that. Not writing this as an answer because I don't know how to do that. A good start would be to define how you got your input points in the first place.

Comment: you were likely loading in a sequence of points from disconnected polygons, which is the wrong approach. It is critical to group the points from each polygon. Is this grouping information available for each point collection?

Comment: yes, it's available, but without correct order to builds polygon

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your points are not in the correct order to define a polygon., and as the commenter pointed out, you have more than one polygons.
You could divide them into sets that make each polygon (manually?), and construct a multipolygon as follows:

```
 SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Collect(ARRAY[ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON(..first polygon...)'),ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON(..2nd polygon...)',...,ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON(..last polygon...)')]));
```

Comment: I don't know the correct order, because i get the points from image in java

Comment: alright, if you dont want a perfect reconstruction, try http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ConcaveHull.html

Comment: But if what you want to do is to reconstruct a picture with polygons into a geometry in postgis, I suggest you make it a new question. I think it's quite hard.

Comment: I make a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642860/save-polygon-from-image-to-postgis-database :)