# save polygon from image to PostGIS database

Tags: java, polygon, postgis

I'm working on a software to detect buildings from satellite imagery.

so far I have managed to separate the building with other objects of the image. 
My problem now is how to save every building in the shape of a polygon into a PostGIS database?

Are there libraries available ata function in java and PostGIS?[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [java image white color extraction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558273/java-image-white-color-extraction)

Answer (score 0):

Add the image to postgis using the python function raster2pgsql, http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/dataadmin/pgGettingStarted/raster2pgsql.html

Then, you can use ST_DumpAsPolygons to convert your image to vectors, based on a range of contiguous pixel values. See http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_DumpAsPolygons.html

The general idea is that you create a polygon from a range of pixel values, though in your case that would appear to be just 255.

You could actually do the building detection directly in Postgis in this fashion, assuming that the buildings take on sufficiently unique values.

What is the blue, as a matter of interest?.

Comment: But, you want to convert them to polygons, no? This is what ST_DumpAsPolygons does? Are you saying you don't want the overhead of loading the image into Postgis first?

Comment: I actually want to avoid storing the image into PostGIS, is there a way to take each polygon using Java?

Comment: There will be edge detection and feature extraction libraries in java, for sure. But, sorry, that isn't really my area. How did you create the outlines in the first place -- it seems like you have done edge detection already, which is the first step towards feature extraction.